# Batch Start Method Best Practice: DML/Scheduling?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, bestpractice

During some solutioning design, my team has come across some complexity around batch scheduling. In order to maintain performance, we've been asked if it is okay to schedule the follow up batch in the `start` method rather than the `finish` method. Our initial response was that doing so would violate best practice, but not sure how to clearly articulate the potential risks which outweigh any benefit. Is changing the state of the database acceptable for a method which returns a query locator? What are the concrete risks involved, aside from potential job collision if Job1 is still running when Job2 kicks off?

Comment: is this conceptually any different that a schedulable starting 2+ batchables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the start method "chaining" won't work. Database.executeBatch from a start method results in:

> |FATAL_ERROR|System.AsyncException: Database.executeBatch cannot be called from a batch start, batch execute, or future method.

It's not even against best practice, it's literally a design limitation. Go with the Schedulable method calling two database.executeBatch methods instead.

Sometimes it's worth checking the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) and other documentation before even contemplating a solution.

Comment: I was more interested in `scheduleBatch`. Same behavior?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, same behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I could have figured that out meself. Now I know.